How to use Google Calendar REST API in an Android app?
I'm trying to integrate Google Calendar API into my Android app to allow users to create, update, and delete events. I've followed the official documentation and added the necessary dependencies, but I'm encountering some issues.
Note that I don't mind how to do it I just want to be able to insert events into the user's Calendar (even asking the user for APIKEY and use it, it's a valid option but couldn't get the API to work with APIKEY)
for example, I try to GET the calendar List (no input required) "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList" and I get:
"code": 401,
"message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",                                                    
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",

Here's what I've tried so far:

GoogleSignIn - couldn't find a way to get accessToken and use it in the API, to get AccessToken it require me to have "redirect_uri", couldn't find a way to make it work with an android only application

from logged in user :


     val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
     val accessToken = credential.accessToken

As it says in Google Deco, but got "Unresolved reference: accessToken"

2nd way from logged in user:

     val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
     val authCredential = credential.zza()

This returns "com. google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential", couldn't find a guide on how to use it like I need.

Also looked at the new AuthorizationClient, but yet again, couldn't find how to use it like I need.

Thanx for any help in advance

for android you should be using a mobile client.   also you dont want signin you want authorization.
